# How to get div height based on image height?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some flip boxes that need a specific height. Otherwise, it does not work.

I gave them `height: 220px;` for testing. But this value shouldn't be `220px`, it always should be the actual proportional image height.

How is it possible to code that? Maybe with a jQuery function? Like: Get the height of the image, and add it as CSS for the container?

This is my code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flip_box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 50%;
  height: 220px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip_box_inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip_box:hover .flip_box_inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip_box_front,
.flip_box_back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_box_front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip_box_back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be possible without JavaScript. It's enough to not specify height for `<div>` and it will stretch to the height of the image.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flip_box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 50%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip_box_inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip_box:hover .flip_box_inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip_box_front,
.flip_box_back {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_box_front {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip_box_back {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(0, -100%) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the containers, search for the image and retrieve the height, then assign it back to the container.

```
jQuery( window ).on( "load", function($) {
    $( ".flip_box" ).each(function( index ) {
        let imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
        $(this).css('height', imgHeight + 'px')
      });
});
```

But note that if images have different heights, it might cause a problem because you are only using the height of a single image from the container

Answer (score 0):

After a slight delay of waiting for the photos to load, you can iterate over the flip boxes, locate their images, and set their heights to match the image height.

```js
const resizeFlipBoxes = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.flip_box').forEach(flipBox => {
    flipBox.style.height = `${flipBox.querySelector('img').offsetHeight}px`;
  });
};

setTimeout(resizeFlipBoxes, 1);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFlipBoxes);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flip_box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 50%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip_box_inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip_box:hover .flip_box_inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip_box_front,
.flip_box_back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip_box_front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip_box_back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip_box">
    <div class="flip_box_inner">
      <div class="flip_box_front">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="flip_box_back">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg/1000px-Nilgai_%28Boselaphus_tragocamelus%29_male.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to have this "responsive", can I easily put a "$(window).resize(function(){...})" around?

Comment: @Anna_B I just added it.